# Print hello in 64-bit masm

Tags: assembly, x86-64, masm

I'm a noob for programing.
I want to write a program to show hello in 64-bit masm.
I use VS code with ml64.exe and gcc.
The following is what I write:

```
;; file name: hello.asm
printf proto

.data
    messenge dq "hello", 0

.code
main proc
    sub rsp, 40h
    mov rcx, messenge
    call printf
    add rsp, 40h
    ret
main endp

end
```

And I write a script to assemble, link ,and execute:

```
@:: file name: run.cmd
@ml64 /c hello.asm
@gcc -o hello.exe hello.obj
@del *.obj
@hello.exe
```

It goes like this:

```
C:\code\MASM>run.cmd
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler (x64) Version 14.25.28614.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

 Assembling: hello.asm
```

It didn't output hello string.
How could I fix it?

Comment: What if you run those commands from your script yourself? Do you get any error messages or other output?

Comment: Also, `messenge` should be declared using `db`, not `dq`. And `mov rcx, messenge` is not the correct way of placing the address of a label in a register. In 32-bit code you'd use `mov ecx, offset message` (or `lea ecx, message`), but I don't know if there are any special considerations for 64-bit code (e.g. in terms of `rip`-relative addressing).

Comment: IT WORKED! I change `dq` to `db`, and `mov rcx, messenge` to `mov rcx, offset message`.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I build this with just `ml64 hello.asm` (no gcc).

```
;; file name: hello.asm
printf proto
includelib msvcrt.lib
includelib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib

.data
    messenge db "hello", 13, 0

.code
main proc
    sub rsp, 40h
    mov rcx, offset messenge
    call printf
    add rsp, 40h
    ret
main endp

end
```

Basically what Michael said.

Comment: I couldn't get exe file from ml64, I guess I didn't use it correctly.
So I still use my script.
This code goes well even without libraries.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you remember to remove the `/c` from your ml64 line?  You should just be doing `ml64 hello.asm`. Nothing really wrong with using gcc, it's just a bit cleaner if you use the linker that came with the assembler.

Comment: Yes, I tried `ml64 hello.asm`. Nothing outputs.

Comment: This prints ```ello``` to the console with a space in front.

Answer (score 3):

I use **Visual Studio 2022** in **Windows 11**. The following code run OK on my machine.

**step1: Create a file `hello.asm` with contents:**

```
includelib ucrt.lib
includelib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib
includelib msvcrt.lib

option casemap:none

.data
; , 10 means line feed character (LF)
; , 0 means adding an terminating '\0' to the string
fmtStr byte 'Hello', 10, 0

.code
externdef printf:proc
externdef _CRT_INIT:proc
externdef exit:proc

main proc
    call _CRT_INIT
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    sub rsp, 32
    lea rcx, fmtStr  ; lea: load the address of a variable into a register
    call printf

    xor ecx, ecx ; the first argument for exit() is setting to 0
    call exit
main endp

end
```

**step2: open "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022" windows, assemble and link the code**

This step use `ml64.exe`, the MASM assembler, together with link options, to generate `hello.exe`:

```
ml64 hello.asm /link /subsystem:console /entry:main
```

**step3: Run the executable**

```
hello.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

For

```
ml64 hello.asm
```

to work, you need to set the LIB environment variable on the command line to:

```
set LIB="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64"
```

You can use File Explorer to find the x64 versions of libcmt.lib, kernel32.lib and ucrt.lib and substitute them to the above LIB setting.

`ml64.exe` is located in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\Hostx64\x64
```

which you need to add to your PATH variable.

Then:

```
ml64 hello.asm
```

It will create `hello.exe` that you can run.

Comment: Successed! Thank you very much!