# Can't call an assembly function from a .cpp file with all in the same project

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, 64-bit, intel, masm

This is the scenario that I am working with. I have a 64 bit kernel mode driver project that I'm compiling and building in Visual Studio 2019 Community with the target OS being Windows 8.1 64 bit. This project contains an **MyASM.asm** file which in turn has a single assembly function defined (see below). The project compiles and builds successfully. So far so good. Now the problem that I'm having is when I try calling this single assembly function from **main.cpp** file the system crashes by freezing and locking up no BSOD. What can be causing this to happen ? Have I got the syntax correct for the .asm file am I missing anything ?

```
================================= MyASM.asm file ====================================
EXTERN DbgPrint:PROC

.data
    dbgString byte "ATest() routine has been CALLED!\n", 0

.code

main PROC

main ENDP

ATest PROC PUBLIC

    ;MOV RDX, Offset dbgString
    ;PUSH [RDX]
    ;CALL DbgPrint
    ;POP RDX        ;***check to see if DbgPrintEx cleans up the stack***
    ;RET

    SUB RSP, 40h
    MOV RCX, offset dbgString
    CALL DbgPrint
    ADD RSP, 40h
    RET

ATest ENDP

END

============================== main.cpp file ==============================
extern "C" void ATest(void);

NTSTATUS
DriverEntry(
    _In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT     DriverObject,
    _In_ PUNICODE_STRING    RegistryPath)
{
    // NTSTATUS variable to record success or failure
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    
    status = ByePgInitialize(SystemWideExceptionHandler, TRUE);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) return status;
    
    // Allocate the driver configuration object
    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG config;

    // Print "Hello World" for DriverEntry
    //KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "KmdfHelloWorld: DriverEntry\n"));
    
    // Initialize the driver configuration object to register the entry point for the
    // EvtDeviceAdd callback, KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd
    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG_INIT(&config,
        KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd
    );

    // Finally, create the driver object
    status = WdfDriverCreate(DriverObject,
        RegistryPath,
        WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES,
        &config,
        WDF_NO_HANDLE
    );
    
    if (status != STATUS_SUCCESS)
        return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
    else
        ATest();
    
}
```

Comment: You forgot to set up shadow stack space in `ATest`.  Review the ABI document for the correct function call sequence.

Comment: In case you need it, the discussion for windows' x64 calling convention is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-software-conventions?view=msvc-170).

Comment: It's a lot easier to debug user-space code (e.g. single-step with a debugger), although you still can do that with a VM for kernel code.  I'd definitely recommend playing around with asm in user-space first, since you have multiple bugs, not just the lack of shadow space.  e.g. pushing the first 8 bytes of string data, rather than `push rdx` to push the pointer.  Also, does DbgPrint even take a stack arg, instead the first arg in RCX like the normal Windows x64 calling convention?  Also, are you sure you want to use a 64-bit absolute address for `dbgString`, instead of a RIP-relative LEA?

Comment: @fuz thank you. You were right I needed to allocate shadow stack space for the procedure. Peter your comments were also correct with respect to using RCX register to load the offset address. I've edited the source code to take into account these changes. All is working. Now if one of you can post an answer with the changes you both have suggested I will accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: @JonnyBGood Just post the answer you found yourself!  This is a very good way to contribute to do the site.

Answer (score 0):

A big thanks to fuz and PeterCordes and the source code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70661294/print-hello-in-64-bit-masm).

```
main proc
    sub rsp, 40h
    mov rcx, offset dbgstring
    call printf
    add rsp, 40h
    ret
main endp
```